# How parametrize delay @BackOff spring boot, @Retry

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11, spring-retry

I can't use my propertie for asign value to delay:

```
 @Value("${delayReintentos}")
 private long delay;

@Retryable(value = { SQLException.class }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = delay))
    public String simpleRetry() throws SQLException {
        counter++;
        LOGGER.info("Billing Service Failed "+ counter);
        throw new SQLException();

    }
```

Java11, Spring boot

Comment: The error is: The value for annotation attribute Backoff.delay must be a constant expression

Answer (score 3):

Use `delayExpression` instead

```java
/**
 * An expression evaluating to the canonical backoff period. Used as an initial value
 * in the exponential case, and as a minimum value in the uniform case. Overrides
 * {@link #delay()}.
 * @return the initial or canonical backoff period in milliseconds.
 * @since 1.2
 */
String delayExpression() default "";
```

See the readme: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#readme

You can use SpEL or property placeholders

```
@Backoff(delayExpression = "${my.delay}",
                        maxDelayExpression = "@integerFiveBean", multiplierExpression = "${onePointOne}")
```

Comment: I need  every 15 minutes with a 4 minutes delay, I can do it with delay expression?

Comment: `>every 15 minutes with a 4 minutes delay` it's not clear what that means.

Comment: I need every 15 minutes with a 4 minutes multiplier delay

Comment: Such long delays are not really recommended since the calling thread is suspended for the delay, consider using a task scheduler for the retries instead. That said, set `maxDelayExpression = "${my.delay}"` with `my.delay=900000` and `multiplierExpression = "${my.mult}"` with `my.mult=240000` (and some cap in `maxDelayExpression`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by wrapping the property name in braces.

```
@Retryable(value = SQLException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${delay}")
```